# How does cv::Ptr<CvHaarClassifierCascade> be released?

Tags: opencv, pointers, memory-management

Assuming:

```
CvHaarClassifierCascade* pCascade;

cv::Ptr < CvHaarClassifierCascade > ptrCascade;
```

Assuming the xml file has been loaded in both `pCascade` and `ptrCascade`. Now we try to release them.

In OpenCV, there is a function `cvReleaseHaarClassifierCascade` to release `pCascade`, as directly deleting `pCascade` will cause a crash.

So how will `ptrCascade` be released?

It seems `cv::Ptr< T >` would use `delete T*` directly.

Or would `cvReleaseHaarClassifierCascade` be called? If so, how does `cv::Ptr` know which `cvRelease*` function should be called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d0/de7/structcv_1_1Ptr.html) of `cv::Ptr<T>` shows that some types from the OpenCV C API already have a `DefaultDeleter` specialization that calls the appropriate release function.

Also, try not to use the old C API. Use the newer `CascadeClassifier` for new projects instead.